# Interview questions about last things you do in your to-do list

Tags: interviewing

I was asked in an interview that **What do you find always left until last on your to-do list?**. I understand that it varies by person. I don't want a direct answer but want to understand the question.

Comment: @SandraK For sure, I always put tasks on top which is very critical. For example, I have to submit this project before 9 pm. I do it first. I keep grocery, laundry at last. But I do not think I should mention these things when they ask me in context of work. That's why I asked the question that what can we really put that relates to job or workplace.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just tell the truth? I know this is a strange concept to a lot of people, but in my experience, telling the truth is usually the best idea, even in job interviews. If it's an embarrassing truth or something negative, feel free to include some context for it but really, the interviewer is just trying to understand how your mind works so they can figure out if you fit with them or not.

Comment: Ok, so you want us to tell you how to answer the question honestly without answering it honestly. Sorry, no can do. Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Cronax That sounds great to me.

Comment: Your comment makes it even more unclear. You already answered the question honestly, so are you asking us how to answer it without being honest while also making you look good?

Comment: I haven't had a to-do-list getting anywhere close to the last items in the last few years. At the moment I have about 6 to 8 months worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are asking what's the last thing you do on your to-do list, just tell them the lowest priority thing you do at your current/past jobs within the context of your actual position. A key thing you might want to bring up, is that you decide what has the lowest priority by discussing it with your supervisor and acting on it. This shows that you are capable of asking for help, prioritizing, and getting things done when they need to be.

**This tells them honestly what you do last, but clarifies that there is nothing negative about that task.**

As an example, if they ask that question in the context of work, then say "I normally complete X task last, because after having discussions with my supervisor, we found that it is the lowest priority."

If they are asking about your personal life, then sure, talk about laundry and groceries.